# Remove background in react native

Tags: react-native, expo

I have updated my react native and expo version and it set grey background that I can not remove or I just do not know how. Help me please, I tried to remove it like this:

```
<View style={{background: 'white'}}></View>
```

but it did not help, when the page was loading it had grey background and when it loaded it became white, but I want to make it white at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
backgroundColor: 'transparent'
```

If you are using react-navigation try:

```
cardStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' },
```

Comment: where to put cardStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' }?

Comment: Supposingly that you use react-navigation, lets say you create a stack navigaton `const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({/*screens*/},{/*settings*/})` inside the function you should have two objects, the first one the screen and the second the settings. In the second object you can add `cardStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' },`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this issue allow me to bestow this knowledge upon you so youdo not suffer as i have. As of Expo SDK v44, they've added "SystemUI" class which has a function "setBackgroundColorAsync"

So you can simply do this:

```
import * as SystemUI from "expo-system-ui";
...
 async function onload() {
    const color = "#000000" // 8 digit hex color code
    await SystemUI.setBackgroundColorAsync(color);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    onload()
  }, [])
```

references:

https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-44-4c4b8306584a

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/system-ui/